# Why can't I play puzzles on Lichess?

Tags: puzzles, lichess

Lichess is a blind-accessible chess site that I like to play. But for some reason, it doesn't support puzzles in an accessible way.

I've done everything that I need to do to make them accessible. But they still aren't, even though it seems possible.

Why aren't puzzles accessible on Lichess for the vision-impaired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the [Lichess database site for puzzles](https://database.lichess.org/#puzzles) I found a link, where someone implemented an interface to solve puzzles "blindfolded" (i.e. without seeing the board):

https://www.tryit.in/blindfoldpuzzles/

However, because of my nonexistent knowledge in that matter, I have no idea if it's usable by blind people. It also seems limited to puzzles with very few pieces.

Answer (score 4):

I just found out that Lichess has changed the way they do puzzles. If you were to enable accessibility mode under settings, you can go straight to Lichess' puzzle page and type out your moves to solve the puzzles. The site has also provided additional information such as where the pieces are, if your move is correct if you've entered a wrong move, what steps it took for the computer to get to that position, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I am making a website called [odinchess.com](https://odinchess.com) that is exclusively for blindfold chess. The games are by text (PGN/SAN notation) and so are the tactics! I'd love for you to check it out - hopefully it can help.

Let me know if there is anything I can add to it that might make it easier to use. I am curious, how do you prefer to be presented the board for tactics? There would need to be some way for you to know what the current position is.